# Use array of emails and names from database in PHPMailer

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send an email from a form to all the emails in a MySQL database.

I've managed to get the form to send an email to each email but I'm now trying to use their name in the email sent to them meaning each email woud begin with "Hello, [their-name],".

I'm using an array to loop through the results of my database query and adding each email and name as `$mail->addAddress('email@email.com, 'name');`

I've tried saving the variable `$name = $row['name'};` inside the while loop but it inputs the last name from the database into all the emails.

My question is: Is it possible to access the `'name'` part of the function and use it each email. Or is it better to take their name from the database itself? And if so how would I go about doing that?

Also, when the email sends to each recipient, it shows all of the recipients in the "To:" field. This would be pretty bad for privacy. Is there a way to prevent this?

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL still so explanatory answers would be greatly appreciated.

Please find my code below.

```html
<?php

// Take message value from form
$message = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r/", "<br />", $_REQUEST['message']);
$message = trim($message);

// Error reporting on
error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

// Require PHPMailer
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'my@email.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->setFrom('myemail@email.com', 'Me');
$mail->addReplyTo('myemail@email.com', 'Me');
$mail->Subject = "Newsletter";
   /* ----- Add address function below ----- */
// Require Database connection
require 'dbcon.php';

// SELECT email and name values from database
$query = "SELECT email, name FROM customers";

// Result = the database query
$result = $con->query($query);
// Get array of users email addresses and names.
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
// Add recipients from values found in database
$mail->addAddress($row["email"], $row["name"]);
 
}
  /* ----- Add address function above ----- */

$mail->Body ="Hello, <br> <br> $message";
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent.";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

print 'Sent!';

?>
```

Comment: Currently you are looping through all your customers and adding each address to one email with the same content and then sending (don't do this - privacy issues).  Whereas it sounds as if you want to send individual personalised emails to each customer.

Comment: The `$message` from the form will be the same for each recipient. But yes, I'd like to personalise the first line of each email.

Comment: You were right @Progrock. Along with Dave's answer, you've really helped me out!

Comment: Instead of asking here and having to wait for a reply, look at the code you've already got! [The mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) provided with PHPMailer does exactly what you ask, much more efficiently than any of the solutions posted here!

Comment: Thanks @Synchro! I had a look before at that and it looks great. However I'm trying to build my own just for my own personal development. I highly doubt I'll ever be using this for a paying client. Just trying to learn new things!

Comment: No problem with that, but if you're going to learn stuff, learn it the right way - the best way to avoid bad habits is not to acquire them in the first place!

Comment: That's good advice! Would you mind quickly mentioning which bad habits you're referring to? So that I can unlearn them asap

Comment: For PhpMailer there is advice for sending to lists like sorting your email list by domain name.  See: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently setting up to send a single email with several recipients.  For security and etiquette, you should address the email to yourself (outside the loop):

```
$mail->addAddress('myemail@email.com', 'Me');
```

...and then add all of the recipients as BCC (inside the loop):

```
$mail->addBCC($row["email"], $row["name"]);
```

As for the name field.  Add a debug line inside your loop and take a look at your output.  Is the name field the same each time?

```
print "Adding recipient: {$row['email']} {$row['name']}";
```

If you want to sent several emails, one to each recipient, you need to instantiate a new email inside the loop each time.

[UPDATE]

If you want to send a single message to each recipient, then instantiate a new email each time (inside your loop):

```
<?php

// Take message value from form
$message = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r/", "<br />", $_REQUEST['message']);
$message = trim($message);

// Error reporting on
error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

// Require PHPMailer
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

// Require Database connection
require 'dbcon.php';

// SELECT email and name values from database
$query = "SELECT email, name FROM customers";

// Result = the database query
$result = $con->query($query);
// Get array of users email addresses and names.
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{

    // Instantiate a NEW email
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    // Set the email settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = 'my@email.com';
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
    $mail->setFrom('myemail@email.com', 'Me');

    $mail->addReplyTo('myemail@email.com', 'Me');
    $mail->Subject = "Newsletter";

    // Add recipient from values found in database
    $mail->addAddress($row["email"], $row["name"]);

    $mail->Body ="Hello, <br> <br> $message";
    $mail->AltBody = $message;

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Message could not be sent.";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
    }

    print "Sent mail to: {$row["email"]}, {$row["name"]}";

}


?>
```

Comment: Upvote for the BCC part, that seems to have solved that problem. I added the debug line but it shows my only the last email from the database still so it's still only saving the last value.

Comment: Just saw your update. That worked! Thanks so much. Everything from hiding the other recipients to displaying their names in each email. Like I said, I'm fairly new to PHP so tips like this on the way loops are structured are very much appreciated!

Comment: Don't create a new instance every time, it's a waste of resources and will also be much slower.

Comment: Personally, I would instantiate the object each time, as suggested, to avoid confusing and messy code.  New email, new object.  Your code will be easier to read and understand.  Let the computers do the work.